# Update table with items where the date is the maximum

Tags: mysql, max

MySQL
I need to update only the rows in a table that have the maximum date grouped by an another column.

Table Objectversions

```
id, ObjectID, objectdatetime, Linktime, othercolumns
```

I have tried

```
UPDATE Objectversions
    SET Linktime = 1
WHERE id IN ( 
                SELECT id 
                FROM Objectversions 
                WHERE Objectdatetime IN (
                        SELECT MAX(Objectdatetime) 
                        FROM Objectversions 
                        GROUP BY ObjectID
                    )
        );
```

I get an error You can't specify target table Objectversions for update in FROM clause.

I have looked at other solutions and cannot work out how to do this. I'll be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using join instead:

```
UPDATE Objectversions t
JOIN ( 
      SELECT id 
      FROM Objectversions 
      WHERE Objectdatetime IN (
             SELECT MAX(Objectdatetime) 
             FROM Objectversions 
             GROUP BY ObjectID) 
 ) s
 ON(t.id = s.id)
SET t.Linktime = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am getting a error, You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I prefer @sagi solution another way of doing it is wrapp the subquery in an outer query.

```
UPDATE Objectversions
    SET Linktime = 1
WHERE id IN ( SELECT t1.id FROM (SELECT id 
                                 FROM Objectversions 
                                 WHERE Objectdatetime IN (
                                                           SELECT MAX(Objectdatetime) 
                                                           FROM Objectversions 
                                                           GROUP BY ObjectID
                                                           )
                
                                 ) as t1
            );
```

You will find a detailed explanation in the documentation about the error [You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)